# create nhibernate conditional query with JoinAlias and the same alias

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm trying to create a condiniotal query in NHibernate and there is an alias that retuned in more than one condidion.
i'm getting and exeption of **duplicate alias**.

what is the way to resolve this issue?

my code is:

```
City parentCityAlias = null;
Country parentCountryAlias = null;

var streetsQuery = _session.QueryOver<Street>();

if (request.cityId.HasValue)
{
    streetsQuery = streetsQuery.Where(t => t.ParentCity.Id == request.cityId);
}

if (request.countryId.HasValue)
{
    streetsQuery = streetsQuery.JoinAlias(t => t.ParentCity, () => parentCityAlias)
               .Where(() => parentCityAlias.ParentCountry.Id == request.countryId.Value);
}


IEnumerable<Street> streets = streetsQuery.List();
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create an `if` statement that refactors the `JOIN` so that both conditions can use it. That is:

```
if (condition1 || condition2)
{
    streetsQuery.JoinAlias(t => t.ParentCity, () => parentCityAlias);
}

if (condition1)
{
    streetsQuery.Where(() => parentCityAlias.ParentCountry.Id == /* .. */);
}

if (condition2)
{
    streetsQuery.Where(() => /* condition 2 */);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.but it was just a semple. there are a lot of conditions and aliases. i lokk for a generic solution.